# Why i signOut in aws cognito didn't revoke access token in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

i have lambda Function for signOut session or user in aws cognito. but, token still can access the api gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token should be valid until it expires. The user signOut ends the session and prevents token refresh, but the already-issued token retains its validity until the refresh cycle is hit.